# How to dynamically add feature image wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have many post posts in my WordPress but i need to add dynamically feature images to all of them through SQL

i tried searching in the SQL but no luck where is the feature image row

Comment: may this solution helps you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57669/retrieve-featured-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get feature image url dynamically by:

```
$img= wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ),'full');
<?php echo $img[0]; ?>
```

here full is the image size you can change to any sez that is given by WP